# Issue with an endpoint - can't post - foreignkey option missing (DjangoREST)

Tags: python, django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

So this is what my user api looks like:

```
{
"count": 1,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "FOOBAR",
        "Todo_List": [
            {
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/todolist_api/1/",
                "default": true,
                "name": "Chores",
                "todos": [
                    {
                        "url": "http://localhost:8000/todos_api/1/",
                        "todolist_id": 1,
                        "name": "Laundry",
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "http://localhost:8000/todos_api/2/",
                        "todolist_id": 1,
                        "name": "Sweep floor",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/todolist_api/2/",
                "default": true,
                "name": "Work",
                "todos": [
                    {
                        "url": "http://localhost:8000/todos_api/3/",
                        "todolist_id": 2,
                        "name": "Talk to Boss",
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "http://localhost:8000/todos_api/4/",
                        "todolist_id": 2,
                        "name": "Say Hello to Janitor",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
]
}
```

I have 3 API endpoints : user_api, todolist_api, and todos_api

I'm having trouble with my todos_api. I have it set so when a user wants to add another todo for a specific todos_list, they have to send a post request to the todos_api with the todolist's pk and the name of the todo.

Ie: if I wanted to created another todo for "Chores", I'd send a post request to the todos_api with todolist_id = 1, and name = "Dust the computer". The issue that **is the option for the todolist_id is missing**. And When I hit post anyway, I get the error saying todolist_id cannot be null. **I think it might be because theres a foreign key relation.**

This is my serializer.py

```
class TodoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ('url', 'todolist_id', 'name')

class TodoListSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    todos = TodoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TodoList
        fields = ('url', 'default', 'name', 'todos')

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    Todo_List = TodoListSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'Todo_List')
```

And this is my models.py

```
class TodoList(models.Model):
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='todolist')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name+'-'+unicode(self.owner))

class Todos(models.Model):
    todolist = models.ForeignKey(TodoList, related_name='todolist_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='foobar')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

If theres any syntax error anywhere it's due to me swapping my actual api's info with todo and todolist to hide my api's idea [the problem is not syntax related].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you shouldn't need the `todolist_id` as you can get it from the parent data.

If you really can't do without, you should fix the serializer's create/update code to pass the parent's todolist as an argument to the todo creation:

```
Todos.objects.create(todolist=todolist, ...)
```

Comment: how would I go about getting it from the parent data? Also how would I go about making a endpoint that takes that parent data?

This is how my front end is structured:

[todolists] -->

[todolist1, todolist2, todolist3, addnewtodolist] --> 

if a todolist is selected then , each of the todo listed along with an option to add a new todo 

[todo1, todo2, todo3, addnewtodo] (this part, the addnewtodo would have the customized todolist_id, obtained from the parent data -it'll send a post to the todos_api - but the todos_api only accepts the following parameters: name...

Comment: For one thing, you don't have 3 endpoints. You have one that has nested data. In the serializer's create/update you create the objects and have a full access to the entire data, so it's up to you to get the todolist and pass it along to the Todo.

Comment: Hey thanks, I decided to use rest_framework_nested to allow my serializers to accept url slugs as arguments. I then did what you said which was to change the serializer's create/update to utilize the new arguments and it worked.